# Simple wxPython Frame Contents Resizing - Ratio?

Tags: python, wxpython, boxsizer

I have a wxPython app with one frame and one panel.  On that panel are a number of static boxes, each of which has buttons and textboxes.

I have just begun reading about sizers, but they seem like they might be more than what I need, or it could that they are exactly what I need but I don't know how to use them correctly!

The frame currently opens at 1920 x 1080.  If the user drags the bottom right corner to resize the app, I just want everything to get smaller or larger as needed to keep the same size ratio.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

edit: additional info: I used wxPython 2.8 and Boa to construct the GUI.  I am contemplating trying another gui ide.

So after reading some more about sizers, I am thinking about doing the following:
add a gridsizer and basically divide my window's elements into rows and columns, then set each row and column's size as necessary until I achieve the original layout.  Then I guess set the rows and columns to resize correctly?  Is this a decent idea?

Comment: Sounds like you've got the idea, but if you can provide a diagram of how you want your layout to look, someone could probably give you more specific advice.  Sometimes BoxSizers can let you accomplish the same thing more easily than the grid sizers.  They let you set a proportion (ratio) when you add widgets to them, and they can be nested inside one another.

Answer (score 1):

For complex layouts, I sketch it out on a piece of paper. Then I draw boxes around the widgets in different ways to decide what sizers to use. You can nest pretty much any sizer inside another one. If the controls naturally fit in a grid, then using a grid sizer of some sort is probably alright. If not, then use BoxSizers. I tend to use those the most.